# DbFunctions Equivalent for EF Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Is there an alternative to [System.Data.Entity.DbFunctions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbfunctions%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) for Oracle? I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework as my provider and need to do some light work with dates.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question ... What do you need to do that requires an alternative to DbFunctions? Do you need a function that isn't available in DbFunctions?